# How to define the logarithm from positive definite matrices to symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

Let $S$ be the set of positive definite matrices, and $\mathfrak s$ the set of symmetric matrices.  The exponential map $\exp: \mathfrak s \rightarrow S$ is a smooth bijection. To argue that it is a diffeomorphism, I would like to define a smooth inverse $\log: S \rightarrow \mathfrak s$.  For $B \in S$, the series

$$\log(B) \;\; =\;\; \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} (I - B)^k$$
only converges when the eigenvalues of $B$ are between $0$ and $2$.  Perhaps a way we can define $\log$ in general is by setting $\log(B) = P^{-1} \log(PBP^{-1})P$, where $P$ is any orthogonal matrix such that $PBP^{-1}$ is diagonal, and for diagonal positive definite matrices we define the logarithm of $\operatorname{diag}(\alpha_1, ... , \alpha_n)$ to be $\operatorname{diag}(\log(\alpha_1), ... , \log(\alpha_n))$.

How can we show that this map is well defined and smooth?

Comment: By the way, I guess you can also use the series. Just take $\log(B)=\log\left(\frac{1}{\|B\|}B\right)+\log(\|B\|)I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix and $\|B\|$ is the norm of $B$, that is, the largest eigenvalue.

Comment: Thanks.  That seems like a pretty good way to do it.  Is it obvious that $B \mapsto ||B||$ is smooth on $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb R)$?

Comment: Good point, I guess it is not smooth. But anyway, you can always move a neighborhood of any symmetric matrix to the desired interval $(0,2)$. It's probably better to use some constant, so $\log(B)=\log\left(\frac{1}{\alpha}B\right)+\log\alpha\,I$. Then you have to show that this is well defined.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is called *functional calculus*. You can try to google this term, although you will probably find mostly stuff regarding operators on Hilbert spaces rather then just finite-dimensional matrices.

On finite dimension, this process is very simple. Take any normal matrix $A$ and any continuous function $f\colon\sigma(A)\to\mathbb{C}$, where $\sigma(A)$ is the spectrum of $A$. (In case of positive operators, you may take functions $f\colon \mathbb{R}^+\to\mathbb{C}$.)

Now, what you are suggesting is essentially to choose a basis of eigenvectors $x_i$ corresponding to eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ (so $Ax_i=\lambda_i x_i$) and define a new operator $B$ by $Bx_i=f(\lambda_i)x_i$. This is surely well defined and we can denote $B=:f(A)$

Slightly "more standard" formulation is the following. You can always do so-called *spectral decomposition* of the operator $A$. This means to write it in the form $A=\sum_i \lambda_i P_i$, where $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of $A$ and $P_i$ are orthogonal projections to the corresponding eigenspaces. Then you can define
$$f(A):=\sum f(\lambda_i)P_i.$$

Now you can try to prove all the stuff you need. Namely that the mapping of matrices induced by $f$ is again continuous, how does the derivative look like and so on.

Comment: You comment should be the answer. The above doesn't address the question.

Comment: What? He did not ask about the series.He asked about the idea of diagonalizing the matrix and then applying the function on the diagonal entries, which is precisely functional calculus as I described here.